# Qt 5.1.1 compiler setup on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, gcc

First of all, I should point out that I've never used linux before.

I have a clean install of 64bit ubuntu, I downloaded Qt 5.1.1 for linux 64 bit from http://qt-project.org/downloads, ran the .run file, installed it and gcc which is included in that download, opened Qt Creator, made a new project and tried to compile it. It wont compile and I keep getting this error message

:-1: error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.

I added a gcc compiler, but what do I need to put for the compiler path, platform codegen flags, platform linker flags and ABI?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to input the path of your compiler because gcc and g++ paths are available in the $PATH enovironment variable. So just use "gcc" and "g++" and that should work. Just make sure you restart Qt Creator after the installation of g++.

One more thing. You need a compiled version of Qt installed on your computer. So also install Qt libraries with

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
```

If you want to use the new version of the library you have to add it to $PATH. You can do this in the terminal with

```
export PATH=/path/to/Qt/qtbase:$PATH
```

And then run Qt Creator from the same terminal, in which you did the last command.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I did that, set the compiler path to "gcc" and now I get the error

:-1: error: g++: Command not found

Comment: @ben1996123 Install g++ with `sudo apt-get install g++`

Comment: Now I'm getting QDialog: No such file or directory and a bunch of "Failed to write to file" errors when qtcreator opens...

Comment: @ben1996123 OK, this means that you don't have writing permissions to the directory where QtCreator is located. So use `chown` and `chmod` to gain writing access to the directory where Qt is installed. But this, anyway, doesn't mean that you have a problem with compiling stuff, right? I think you can compile stuff now, can't you?

Comment: @ben1996123 BTW. I would recommend that you use the default Qt Creator and qt-dev-tools from Ubuntu. I think you still need more experience before using the version from the internet. I now get the opensource version, compile it, and use it. Wait till you get that level of experience then install stuff from the Qt website. And one more recommendation: DON'T install stuff on your root directory. Just install them on your user directory and add the directories to $PATH. This is much easier to fix if you do mistakes, and much easier to update.

Comment: Well, I think I could compile stuff but nothing that uses qt because I don't think I have any of the dlls... Also I'm only using Linux so that I can compile stuff I made on Windows.

Comment: @ben1996123 Using Qt is supposed to be simple, but only if you use the version which is already there in the repos of your system. So just install `sudo apt-get install qt-dev-tools` and don't bother with installing the newest version. And about compiling stuff from Windows to Linux, that's not only not possible, but also is totally another story. You can't always transfer programs from Windows to Linux unless all your libraries are compatible and cross-platform. I still don't know whether your question is answered or not. If your question is answered, use the accept (check mark) symbol.

Comment: Qt is cross platform so that's not a problem. sudo apt-get install qt-dev-tools gives me an error (E: Unable to locate package qt-dev-tools).

Comment: @ben1996123 Try this (I wrote it in the answer): `sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools`

Comment: @ben1996123 If your question is answered you have to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the dependencies as well. I got it working when I followed the steps in the following link.
Try this:
http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git